# Why I should break distinct count measures into separate measure groups?

Tags: sql-server, count, ssas, distinct, olap

When I am trying to create `DistinctCount` measure in VS 2008 OLAP project, it creates it in separate group instead original group that I want.
Therefore, I created it in two steps.
I created measure without aggregation in needed group and then set `AggregationFunction` to `DistinctCount` manually.

Then I've built project and deployed. Everything works fine except warning in OLAP project. My measure is highlighted by a blue wavy line and it says:

> Break distinct count measures into separate measure groups

Why should I do it and is it safe to ignore this warning?

Comment: Is the answer below what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Microsoft white paper entitled **"Analysis Services Distinct Count Optimization"**:

> As a quick high-level overview of distinct count calculations, **the distinct count measure is not designed like other measures (such as sum, count, max, min, and so on)**. Distinct counts are **difficult to aggregate in comparison to other measures because the former are not fully additive**. Because of this, the vast majority of distinct count queries are calculated at run time at the leaf level granularity, specifically the unique values of the distinct count measure. This means that the Analysis Services storage engine parses the source column and treats it almost like an attribute that has been GROUPED BY with an implicit count for each row.

Later they mentioned that:

> As previously noted, **this is because the distinct count measure is architecturally different than other measures**. You cannot have more than one distinct measure because you cannot order a MEASURE GROUP by many measures. **The distinct count measure is also at a lower level of granularity than SUM and COUNT measures**. By adding other measures to the measure group holding a distinct count measure, all of the other measures will be at the same granularity as the distinct count measure, **resulting in inefficient data structures and suboptimal queries**. To perform distinct count aggregations, each distinct count measure still retains its unique combination of dimension key attributes.

You can download the white paper from the following link:

- [Analysis Services Distinct Count Optimization](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=891)